# How to extract time series from a raster stack in R

Tags: r, time-series, r-raster

I have created a RasterStack from NDVI layers of the MODIS data. Now i want to extract time series data from different locations of this data so that i can use BFAST/greenbrown package to estimate trend and breakpoints.
Here is how i have created the stack:

```
#runGdal(Job="testJob","MYD13Q1",begin = "2018.01.09", end = "2018.12.27",
#        tileH = 26:29, tileV = 4:7
#        , SDSstring = "1000000000000000000000") 

###NDVI files path
NDVI_files_path <- "/media/MyData/Data/MODIS/PROCESSED/MYD13Q1.006_20190527193158"
all_NDVI_files <- list.files(NDVI_files_path,
                            full.names = TRUE,
                            pattern = ".tif$")
all_NDVI_files

### Raster Stack
NDVI_stack <- stack(all_NDVI_files)
```

How can i extract time series data for any specific area in Raster stack ?

Comment: A [MCVE] would include any needed `library` calls and a small example that could be used for testing.

Comment: I'd have a look at function raster::extract()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate` and `rts` to create a RasterStackTS object as follows:

```
#Load libraries
library(rts)
library(lubridate)

#Reproducible example (use your files here)
all_NDVI_files = c('MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000049_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000065_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000081_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000097_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000113_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000129_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000145_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000161_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000177_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000193_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000225_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000241_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000257_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000273_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000289_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000305_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000321_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000337_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000353_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001001_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001017_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001033_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001049_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001065_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001081_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001097_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001113_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001129_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001145_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001161_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001177_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001193_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001209_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001225_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001241_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001257_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001273_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001289_aid0001.tif',
               'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2001305_aid0001.tif')

#Depending on file format, extract dates (this example uses MODIS 16-day composite NDVI)
ndvi.time = data.frame(year=substr(basename(all_NDVI_files),34,37),
                julD=substr(basename(all_NDVI_files),38,40))
ndvi.time$dateJ = paste(ndvi.time$year,ndvi.time$julD,sep='-')
ndvi.time$julD = parse_date_time(ndvi.time$dateJ,'y-j')

# create your RasterStackTS object
# Use your actual rasterstack here i.e. it's not reproducible with above code
ndvi.rts = rts(NDVI_stack ,ndvi.time$julD) 
ndvi.rts
plot(ndvi.rts)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the example. i created the time series object but when i want use it in [bfastmonitor](http://bfast.r-forge.r-project.org/) or [greenbrown](http://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/man/Trend.html). it gives me error that `ndvi.rts should be from class 'ts'`. How can i convert the `rts` object created into a `ts` object so i can plot trend graphs shown in the both packages documentations?

Comment: As far as I know [greenbrown](http://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/) doesn't use `RasterStackTS` objects. Just use the original `RasterStack` or `RasterBrick` and add the start and frequency variables like so: `TrendRaster(NDVI_stack, start=min(ndvi.time$julD), freq=23, method='AAT', breaks=4)`. Freq is 23 for 16-day composites (per year).